# Does user managed access (uma) cover row level security

Tags: keycloak, gluu

I am trying to evaluate options for securing enterprise api endpoints. The requirement is to be able to secure endpoints at a fine grained data level eg can user 1 access customer 1.

Get api.com/customer/1

I have discovered gluu and key cloak but I'm not sure if this truly covers my use case as they seem to be about a user granting special permission to another user and not something you would use to secure individual endpoints inside an application.

Answer (score 0):

UMA Resources typically represents endpoint. So answer is yes, Gluu can secure it with any kind of granularity that is needed (via UMA Resource definition and UMA RPT Policy script).

In case of more specific questions Gluu Support can be great place to get help:
https://support.gluu.org